# How to get google sheets cell value to populate text box value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a donut chart where I want the text box in middle of chart to = cell I2.

I can't find this ability online like I can when I do it in excel. Is this possible?

Link to sheet:

Comment: Unfortunately, *directly* linked chart-in-a-cell only supports `line`, `bar`, `column`, `winloss` chart types via [`sparkline`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en). I imagine the devs consider pie charts ill-suited to be be displayed in a single cell and thus low priority to code.

Comment: I should probably mention that it is possible to export the chart programmatically as an image and then you can use `image()` to display it in a cell and the relevant methods have been asked and answered (which is great). However, this indirect linkage takes away the responsiveness of a native chart. You are welcome to ask a separate question on that though.